# Unable to use "Get Element States" Browser Library in Robot Framework

Tags: browser, robotframework

I have earlier used tests using Keyword - Get Element States, but suddenly I see it throws me below err:
No keyword with name 'Get Element States' found. Did you mean:
Browser.Get Element State

I m unsure what could have happened or changed, that is giving this err.
Could some one throw some light on it, I seem to am stuck with this
PS: I have declared Browser Library in the settings section and 'Get Element State' works just fine.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried re-installing Browser Library which did not solve the issue, Tried rebooting the machine, which surprising solved my issue.